# How can I replace certain data strings with predefined data using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to use JavaScript to take data entered into a text field and replace the first two digits with a character and at the same time preserve the remaining digits in the string. The input data will always be 6 digits in length and there are 4 different possible character options depending on the first 2 digits of the input data. Here are the four possible options.

```
00 = A, 01 = M, 31 = B, 71 = F
```

So for example, if the input data is `001234`, the output would need to be `A1234`. If the input is `719999`, the output needs to be `F9999`.

I appreciate any help you can provide and thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Improved coding format

Answer (score 0):

I put it in a Snippet for you to understand what your variables do and how to manipulate it with if statements. A Switch statement should be more suitable. You can ask if needed.

```js
var persNr = "021212"
var strLtr = persNr.substring(0,2); 
var strNum = persNr.substr(2,4); 

if (strLtr == "01"){ 
        strLtrOut = "A" + strNum ; 
        
    } 

if (strLtr == "02"){ 
        strLtrOut = "B" + strNum ; 
        
    } 
    
    
console.log("This is strLtr: " + strLtr);
console.log("This is strNum: " + strNum);
console.log("This is strLtrOut: " + strLtrOut);
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare tc_event; I assume this is a value returned by another function or application. But in your function you call TC_event. Please bare in mind that variables in JS are case sensitive. So tc_event is an  entirely different variable than TC_event.

In your function you don't assing the returned value of strNewFld to tc_event so even while returned, tc_event will remain the initial value.

```js
var persNr = "711212";

var strSrc = persNr ;
    var strLtr = strSrc.substring(0,2); 
    var strNum = strSrc.substr(2,4); 

    console.log("This is strLtr: " + strLtr);
    console.log("This is strNum: " + strNum);

    var strNewFld = "";
    var strLtrOut= "";

// In your if statement you use a single =. This means assign. 
// To compare allways use ==. This compares. 

    if (strLtr == "00"){ 
        strLtrOut = "A"; 
    } 

    if (strLtr == "01"){ 
        strLtrOut = "M"; 
    } 
    
    if (strLtr == "31"){ 
        strLtrOut = "B"; 
    }
    
    if (strLtr == "71"){ 
        strLtrOut = "F";
    } 

   strNewFld = strLtrOut + strNum;   
   // here you could assign value of strNewFld 
   // to tc_event or directly assiging
   // strLtrOut + strNum to tc_event.

   tc_event = strLtrOut + strNum


  console.log("This is strNewFld: " + strNewFld);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gul this works! Thank you for all your help. Very much appreciated